# How can I provision a Docker image using Ansible without installing locally?

Tags: docker, ansible

I would like to use Ansible instead of a Dockerfile to provision a docker image because it is more portable. It is possible to do this without installing Ansible inside the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an ansible plugin connect to Docker containers using `docker exec`. See here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/11650. I think these are the corresponding docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html

Previously there was https://github.com/lorin/ansible-docker-connection but this project seems to refer to the above ticket.

This Ansible role might also be of interest: https://github.com/chrismeyersfsu/provision_docker